# jQuery width() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, width

I'm trying to get the width of the first div of the specific class "span4" on my Bootstrap site, but the script simply fails to execute the second line where I call `width()`. Here's what I have:

```
var span = $('div.span4').first();
spanWidth = span.width();
```

The strange part of this is that I have similar working code immediately after that works fine when I remove the above two lines and set spanWidth to a constant:

```
elements = $('a.backlink');
elements.each(function() {
var a = $(this);
if (a.width() > spanWidth) {
    var aText = a.text();
    var lastIndex = aText.lastIndexOf(' ');
    var aTruncated = aText.substring(0, lastIndex);
    a.text(aTruncated + '...');
}
});
```

Any idea what might be causing this? I've tried a lot of different ways to format those two lines differently, such as switching to an `each()` method, condensing to one line, and using `[0]` and `get(0)` instead of `first()`.

Comment: What `console.log(span)` returns?

Comment: I think that the problem could be forgetting the `var` keyword when setting `spanWidth`...

Comment: Can you show us your HTML portion ..

Comment: @dotbran try to reproduce the same behavior in a jsfiddle

Comment: if your console.log(span) returning undefined ..it means there is no   first div element having a class called span4... you can check the rendered html in browser ..and also is your div is a hidden div ??

Comment: I am Glad that you figured out the problem .. :)

Comment: Please post your solution as an actual answer (which you can later accept) and please don't add words like "answered" or "solved" to the title.

Comment: @ChrisF If this happens in the future is there a better way to temporarily to denote that the question has been answered if I am unable to post an answer?

Comment: @dotbran - The only thing you could do at the moment is leave a comment. I have raised the issue on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/should-we-really-be-suggesting-that-people-put-the-answer-in-the-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SimonM's comment led me to try replacing my implied global `spanWidth` with an explicit global `window.spanWidth`, and now everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the span's display to inline-block.